# Sublime Text 2 Build (Ctrl +B) Intel Fortran Compiler

Tags: linux, fortran, sublimetext2, intel-fortran

I am using ifort 11.1 on Linux 64-bits with Sublime Text2 as editor. I want to know, how can I create a custom build command to compile the code?  Also I need to know how to produce the output with the same name as the source file. For example I want to reproduce the following command into a custom Build System:

```
ifort mycode.f90 -o mycode
```

So far I tried:

```
{
"cmd": ["ifort","$file"],
"selector": ["iFort"],
"path":["/usr/local/Compiler/11.1/080/bin/intel64/ifort intel64"]
}
```

Without success. Ideas?

Comment: Any errors? Have you followed [these](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html?highlight=build) guidelines? Have you tried to troubleshoot according to [these](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#troubleshooting-build-systems) instructions?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
"cmd": ["ifort","$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.fortran90"
```